# the dates return changed from the sql query while the correct rows are selected

Tags: php, sql, datetime, datetime-format

The problem : 
I have a database with a datetime type field to store the date. The date is stored in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format.
I would like to retrieve all rows which are created after a sertain date
I make a simple sql query like:

```
 // the date comes from the form input in the format dd-mm-yyy)
 $d = new DateTime('01-02-2017');
 $convertDate = $d->format('Y-m-d');

 "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order WHERE date_created >= '" . $convertDate . "'";
```

The query returns right rows. But on the front end I see the wrong dates like this in the table below the first column shows the dates form datetime field in database and the first column shows the dates which I get from the query. So a date from the first column turns in the date in the second column...

```
----------------------------------------------
|   database value    |    front end display   |
----------------------------------------------
| 2017-12-04 14:25:28 |  2017-10-30 14:50:45   |
----------------------------------------------
| 2018-01-11 07:56:27 |  2016-11-25 12:48:30   |
----------------------------------------------
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Wrong dates how?

Comment: which dbms do you use? did you try to format your date (’01-02-2017’) in the query?

Comment: Those returned dates in the first column are all bigger or equal than the datestamp variable. So what is that "front end display" actually showing?  Seems more related to the PHP code than the SQL?

Comment: @LukStorms I have edited the question a bit conserning the table.

Comment: @mark I format the date before the query, $convertDate is the formated date. possible I'm doing it wrong. But the returned are correct. I have checked by running the query form the database itself. It gives the same rows as I get from the php query. only the dates are "transformed". What is dbms?

Comment: @LukStorms maybe it is a php issue. how the date is passed to the sql. I have tried different functions already. but it doesn't help.

Comment: I don't see any pattern between the db value and the front end value...it looks like somewhere one the way the variable gets mixed up or manipulated - your query might return several rows, maybe you fetch a new row somewhere along the way?

Comment: @cypherabe thanks, you have brought me to an idea. I have actually simplified the query for the question. In real it is a left join on multiple tables. and it occures that two of those tables have a column with the same name. so the values get mixed up. i have specified from which table which column I would like to get and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. The problem was never in the dates. the problem was the asterix * in the SELECT statement. That occured to me that in some tables the names of the columns could be the same. And it was the case. So on the way to result rows the data from the column date_added in order table was overritten by the date_added column in customer. When I specified the columns along with the alias of the tables I got the right data.

So first the query was like
     "SELECT * FROM order o LEFT JOIN order_total ot ON (..) LEFT JOIN customer c ON (..) LEFT JOIN .... ";

And it has become
     "SELECT o.date_added, o.order_id, .... FROM order o LEFT JOIN order_total ot ON (..) LEFT JOIN customer c ON (..) LEFT JOIN .... ";